# Gpio pins are triggered even without input

Tags: gpio, rpi.gpio, relay

Basically it hooks up to a 12v relay:

https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/0BxdLxDCD6HidZDFfWHhjWEZHYVU

If button is pressed, it should send high to the relay.

The problem I encounter is that if I run the gnd of RPi to Gnd input of relay, my code continues (or it sends an input to pin17) even without me pressing the button...me just holding the wire satisfies the false state.

Do you have an idea what's causing this?

```py
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(18,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(17,GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
#GPIO.setup(17,GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

try:
        while True:
                input_state = GPIO.input(17)
                if input_state == False:# and GPIO.input(27)==1 :
                        print ('Button Pressed'),input_state
                        GPIO.output(18,GPIO.HIGH)
                        time.sleep(0.2)
                GPIO.output(18,GPIO.LOW)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
  print "  Quit"
  # Reset GPIO settings
  GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: GPIO 17 is connected to pin 11.  Is that the pin you are using for the relay?

Comment: @joan nope. I'm using pin 18 for my relay.

Comment: Okay.  The input (button) is using GPIO 17 which is physical pin 11.  The output (to relay) is using GPIO 18 which is physical pin 12. Is that correct?

Comment: @joan Correct! did you encounter this issue before?

Comment: No, you seem to have done everything correctly.  To take this further I think we need a photo of your Pi set up and connections.

Comment: @joan Solved my own problem... added an external pullup resistor like this one [circuit](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/6/f/b/c/7/511568b6ce395f1b40000000.jpg)

Comment: @user3610216 FYI - it is acceptable to [provide an answer to your own question](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) if you want.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading this correctly, the relay is being triggered even without a trigger from the RPI?  If that's the case, I would think that you would need a pull up resistor on the output of the RPI to the relay.  It would stabilize the floating output state that might be triggering the relay.